# using reference from abstract class in a child class of abstract class c

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hullo, first time asking a question!  I have 3 classes, CharacterBuilder, which is an abstract class, BullyCharacterBuilder, which inherits from CharacterBuilder and redefines one of its functions, and Character, which is a generic class full of ints with accessors/mutators that I need to use.

I define a pointer to Character in CharacterBuilder.h like so:

```
    #ifndef CHARACTERBUILDER_H
    #define CHARACTERBUILDER_H
    #include "Character.h"

    class CharacterBuilder {
    public:
        Character* getCharacter();
        void createNewCharacter();
        virtual void buildCharacter(int level) = 0;

    protected:
        Character* leeroy;

    };
    #endif
```

CharacterBuilder.cpp

```
 #include "CharacterBuilder.h"
    #include "Character.h"

    Character* leeroy;

    Character* CharacterBuilder::getCharacter() {
        return leeroy;
    }
    void CharacterBuilder::createNewCharacter(){
        leeroy = new Character;
    }
```

Then I inherit publicly from CharacterBuilder in my BullyCharacterBuilder class like so:

```
#ifndef BULLYCHARACTERBUILDER_H
#define BULLYCHARACTERBUILDER_H

#include "Character.h"
#include "CharacterBuilder.h"

class CharacterBuilder;

class BullyCharacterBuilder : public CharacterBuilder{

    CharacterBuilder* myParent;

 void buildCharacter(int level);
};
#endif
```

Finally, in the cpp file for my BullyCharacterBuilder, I attempt to call accessor/mutators from the Character pointer (which I assume I've inherited from CharacterBuilder) like so:

```
#include "Character.h"
#include "BullyCharacterBuilder.h"
#include "CharacterBuilder.h"

void buildCharacter(int level){
leeroy->setAbilityScores();
}
```

When I attempt to do this, I get **Error: identifier "leeroy" is undefined**
It might be a dumb question but I tried searching for this particular problem on stackoverflow and google using every combination of keywords I could think of.  Would be much obliged to any help!

Comment: You need to be in a method of CharacterBuilder or one of its children to access leeroy. You can't define buildCharacter like that if you want it to be a method of BullyCharacterBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to qualify the function `buildCharacter` with your class name `BullyCharacterBuilder`:

```
void BullyCharacterBuilder::buildCharacter(int level){
leeroy->setAbilityScores();
}
```

Comment: Aha this is it exactly, fixes the issue.  Thanks a lot, and to the two others as well!

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement buildCharacter as a method on the CharacterBuilder class

```
void BullyCharacterBuilder::buildCharacter(int level)
{
  leeroy->setAbilityScores();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you type like this `void buildCharacter(int level)` meaning that the function is independent and don't belong to any class, 
so you must type like this 
`void BullyCharacterBuilder::buildCharacter(int level)` to tell compiler the function belongs to BullyCharacterBuilder